# How to display .obj file with .mtl in Android using Processing

Tags: android, 3d, processing, .obj

I want to run a Processing sketch on Android mode where I load and display an .obj file.
In Java mode it works perfectly but in Android mode the .obj geometry shows up without the materials (.mtl file).

My .obj and .mtl(including png textures) are both in the data folder.

```
PShape s;
void setup() {
  size(720, 1280, P3D);
  s =loadShape("myObject.obj");
}

void draw() {
  background(230);
  lights();
  scale(40);
  shape(s, 10, 10);
}
```

Comment: You might want to report this issue here: https://github.com/processing/processing-android/issues

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that a lot of .obj files will have a relative path in their .mtl reference like so:

`mtllib ./materials.mtl`

In my experience, Processing doesn't like this. If your .obj file has this, try removing the dot slash like this:

`mtllib materials.mtl`